# Better way of introduction on Stack Overflow when a new user is not marking answers

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, new-users

There are many new users I helped on Stack Overflow. They say thanks, but they don't accept (mark) answers as they are not aware of it.

So there should be proper introduction of Stack Overflow to new users. They should be taught about Stack Overflow step-by-step, like taking a tour on Facebook.

The introduction should be done as the new user logs in for the first time, and it should be mandatory to run the introduction session.

And a link should be there to re run the introduction session whenever the new user wants.

Comment: This user never marks answer  http://stackoverflow.com/users/2741803/shameer is a member since 13 days.

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585274/struts2-conversion-of-list-to-integer-or-double-not-working/18590749#18590749), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798866/window-unload-not-working-in-jquery/18798921#18798921), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808830/jquery-checkbox-val-always-return-on/18808835#18808835), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808112/jquery-toggle-function-not-working/18808123#18808123). All of which the OP has said `working` but not accepted. Sucks, but I'd rather not see a tutorial stage to hurdle though.

Comment: @DaveChen there are many users like this.

Comment: Is this a wildly big deal? Frankly I consider the community votes a far more useful mark of helpfulness than the accepted mark

Comment: @RichardTingle: Agree. That's why two upvotes are worth more than an accept. Also note that an accept can be removed at any time, while up/down votes are locked in after a specific amount of time.